# How to interchange steps and scheduled time of an existing job in Microsoft SQL server management studio?

Tags: sql-server

There is an existing job which is scheduled to run daily in Microsoft SQL server management studio. It has 3 steps. I want to interchange the steps (step 2 and step 3 are to be interchanged). I also want to change the scheduled time. Can someone explain me the process to make these changes?

Comment: There is an typo in the question title, you can also provide an example of what is this job is about

Answer (score 0):

Script out jobs from management studio and then rearrange steps and modify schedule in the script.
Places to change should be obvious from the script generated by SMS.

Execute modified script and you are done (caveat changing job name or drop/create existing job)

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to use sql commands to create, modify or grop SQL Agent jobs, it's typically easier and safer to simply find the job in the Object Explorer (SQL Server Agent > Jobs > JobName) and modify it from there.

The Job Properties window will give you the option to rearrange the job steps with simple up/down arrows, from the "Steps" tab, and adjust schedules from the "Schedules" tab.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I have a doubt regarding this. Is rearranging the job steps with up/down arrows enough? Shouldn't the script be changed?

Comment: You said you needed two steps to be "interchanged". What I described above will do that. If you need to change what a step does, then you'll need to look at what code is being executed by that step.